# Text search to return keys in MongoDB or Python Object

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to implement a text search with mongoDB and Python Flask which shall return a Key with a given input query.

My json document represents an article divided by pages, as keys, and the values of the keys is a list of paragraph texts:

```
{ 

   "_id" : ObjectId('eeeeeeeeeee'),

   "title" : "Article Title",

   "1" : ["Some text in 0 position of the list which represents page 1, first paragraph", "Some text in 1 position of the list which represents page 1, second paragraph"],

   "2" : ["random huge text in the second page, paragraph 1", "random huge text in the second page, paragraph 2"] 

 }
```

The numered keys represents the page of the article, and the position of the list represents the paragraph in the page.

For an example, when a user inputs "text position" in a query, the result should be key "1" position 1 of the list.

Not really sure how to implement this. I've created an index using createIndex({"$**":"text"}), and when i query for anything in mongo, it returns the documents sorted by score. If only i could retrieve the json key in which the query is most relevant, most of my problems are solved.

Any tips where i can start with?

Answer (score -1):

Based on mongodb docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#example

For example, you could use the following query to find all stores containing any terms from the list “coffee”, “shop”, and “java”:

```
db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java coffee shop" } } )
```

You can also search for exact phrases by wrapping them in double-quotes. For example, the following will find all documents containing “java” or “coffee shop”:

```
db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java \"coffee shop\"" } } )
```

Comment: Unfortuntaly, this does not answer the question you will not have the ID of the child element but only the ID of the parent element